# Sumo0.32.0 + veins4.7.1: how to simulate multiple specific accidents in the ini file

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using omnet++5.4.1 and veins4.7.1 and sumo 0.32.0. I have already gone through the examples given with the packages and everything works well.
Now, I would like to schedule many accidents in the ini file in order to measure the impact of collisions. For example, instead of

> *.node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1

have something like

> *.node[*10].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
>
> *.node[*13].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
>
> *.node[*16].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1

where all the accidents are scheduled at the same time. The cars enter the network with a period of 3.

I have tried, but just one among the three nodes (always the second one - node[13]) really stops and implement the code related to accidentSchedule. All the other cars stop but don't send anything and instead other random cars (differents from the nodes scheduled), implement the accidentSchedule. Here is what I have at the moment of the accident:

> ** Event #107  t=106  RSUExampleScenario.node[10].veinsmobility (TraCIMobility, id=70)  on selfmsg scheduledAccident (omnetpp::cMessage, id=156)
>
> ** Event #108  t=106  RSUExampleScenario.node[13].veinsmobility (TraCIMobility, id=88)  on selfmsg scheduledAccident (omnetpp::cMessage, id=200)
>
> ** Event #109  t=106  RSUExampleScenario.node[16].veinsmobility (TraCIMobility, id=106)  on selfmsg scheduledAccident (omnetpp::cMessage, id=244

What shows that all the scheduled nodes schedule the accident but don't do what expected.

Please, any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.